# Read e-mail showing up as new the next day

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I've recently set up a new laptop with Outlook 2013. Over the last few days there have been some (but not all) people who have complained about e-mails I've sent from that machine. They will receive mail when I send it but the same mail will reappear unread the next day for some people (and I can only see the mail in the Sent-folder once). For example, I've sent an email two days ago at 22:34 and it has reappeared yesterday and today (with the correct timestamp) as a new mail.

This is a basic POP3-account that keeps mail on the server and it is a shared address for an organisation I volunteer for. There is one other person who reads the mails as well. I copied the .pst from my old computer as it contains an archive of email over 3 years old and older mails are no longer on the server. I've set up the account with the same options I used for previous computers and there is nothing odd or specific about the configuration.

I send mail on multiple accounts from that laptop and there is only one account affected. (they are on different hosts so this might be related to the host and not my client) Some of the mails I send are also sent to another one of my addresses and I only receive that e-mail once. Sometimes I CC the account from which I send to keep the other person using the account in the loop and he will receive the mail twice, whereas everything seems normal for me and I will only receive it once. (Which is very confusing...)

I'm pretty much at a loss what could cause this. Since it only happens when I send I suspect my own mailclient to be at fault but there is nothing odd about the configuration.

Comment: What makes you think the fault is with your set up? Is it happening to all recipients or just some (I know you wrote 'some' but didn't know if you tested it)? Do these reoccurring emails appear multiple times in your sent box?

Comment: I've clarified things a bit in my question. It happens to one recipient in particular, but I had a call this morning from somebody else who also had it happening to them. Before that I thought the problem was with the other client but it appears to happen to multiple people (who are in no way using related systems). They are only in the Sent-folder once.

Comment: You said you have many accounts, but is the faulting account the only one with that domain. EG, if the faulting account was GMAIL, do you use another GMAIL account which works fine?

Comment: It is the only account on that domain with that provider I can send e-mail from but I can't check. Other people use accounts on that domain and they do not appear to have any issues so it would have to be down to the mailbox...

Comment: yes, but the mailbox may be out of your control - see my answer for a couple of suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like it is down to the email provider.

We need to rule out Outlook (or confirm it)... Do you have access to a web mail for this account? If so, send an email from the browser version and see if the issue persists.

If not, can you use a free mail client like Thunderbird or Windows Mail, again to see if the issue persists or not.

Comment: Could indeed confirm that it was not down to my account, contacted the provider and they 'fixed something'. Not sure what they did but seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: @JDT, glad you got it solved. At least you were able to prove it :)